# How to get the output of a function to be used as an input by another function and loop through each line of the output

Tags: linux, bash, shell

```
#!/bin/bash
# expm

# ab function to execute the output from input function one by one
ab () {

ping=$1

sleep 5s

ifconfig=$1
}

read -p "enter values: " Values

# input function to format input on a new line

input () {

echo " $(echo $values | awk '{print $1,$2}' FS='-' RS=' ' OFS='-') "
}

# the below line is to take the input function output and compute it to the ab function one by one

input

while IFS= read -r input; do

    ab "$input"

done
```

The issue I have is when I run the script

./expm w23r.abc:eg-1/23-we34.abc:eg-2/43 we4r.abc:eg-2/25-w5wr.abc:eg-1/63 wewr.abc:eg-6/23-45wr.abc:eg-3/24

it gives the following output only

```
w23r.abc:eg-1/23
we4r.abc:eg-2/25
wewr.abc:eg-6/23
```

My desired goal is to loop the above value through ab function one at a time regardless of how many line the output is

**Script after ShellCheck**

```
#!/bin/bash

# expm

# ab function to execute the output from input function one by one

ab () 

{

ping=$1

sleep 5s

ifconfig=$1

}

read -r "enter values: " values

# input function to format input on a new line

input () {

echo " $(echo "$values" | awk '{print $1,$2}' FS='-' RS=' ' OFS='-') "
}

# the below line is to take the input function output and compute it to the ab function one by one

input

while IFS= read -r input;

do  ab "$input"

done
```

Comment: Please paste your script there first: http://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: [XY Problem?](http://xyproblem.info/)

Comment: I  have added the script after shellcheck.net edit

Answer (score 0):

Not much different from pieces of what you already did.

```
while read -p "enter values: " values # fixed case on var
do ab $( input )
done
```

This isn't going to do anything useful though - you're just silently setting/overwriting vars in that function.

Read the docs, but unless and until you understand functions clearly and have a need for them elsewhere in the program...

```
while read -p "enter values: " values # fixed case on var
do echo "$values" | awk '{print $1,$2}' FS='-' RS=' ' OFS='-'
done
```

Comment: Thank you Paul, the issue seem to continue as the script is giving the below output and not proceeding with the next action. Only the below output is appearing after running the script. Looks like the ab function is not accepting the formatted input (w23r.abc:eg-1/23)?

w23r.abc:eg-1/23

Comment: First make everything work without functions. Then encapsulate it into repeatable functions with sensible I/O. One step at a time. Write unit tests.